# jQuery click to close div (display)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do a function click to open/close one div.

It's basic, but, the click only show the div, and, when i click to "close", nothing happens.

```
$(".inscricao-email").click(function(){
      $("#display-form").css({"display":"block"});
});

$("#form-fechar").click(function(){
      $("#display-form").css({"display":"none"});
});
```

I tried to use addClass / removeClass, but do the same thing (not work).

Help :D

Comment: Just build a small fiddle with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/67LJ8/ - and it seems to be working fine. Did you check the console whether it prints an error?

Comment: What element are you using for the button ?

Comment: The element i'm using is an <a>, because i can't use a <button>. The element is inside an form, and, for some reason, all buttons return like "sending button form". I try to put .epreventDefault, but does'nt work;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

`$("#display-form").toggle()`

**UPDATE:**

As codezombie pointed out your code does work, so there is problem elsewhere in your code (perhaps one of your jQuery selectors).

Answer (score -2):

The jQuery CSS method doesn't take an object as a parameter. It takes two: the CSS property to be changed, and what to change it to. It's very basic; if you're looking for a more 'fancy' effect, then I suggest you use something more along the lines of `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`. But anyway, you can use the CSS method like this:

```
$(selector).css('display', 'inline-block');
```

If you want, you could also make it look a bit more interesting by adding a CSS transition.

Comment: This answer is not correct, as the jQuery `.css()` *does* take an object as parameter. Please see the documentation - http://api.jquery.com/css/ - `.css( properties )`.

Comment: Use [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for fancy CSS transitions. Hint: you would use `.toggleClass()`

Comment: Hm. It appears that it takes both... I just didn't know about the object method of doing it. My mistake, Codezombie.